# How to duplicate a generator below connected media?

Tags: final-cut-pro-x

I have my main story line and then I've added still frames of a presentation throughout. The images are displayed ontop of my video and the images don't cover the entire screen, so I can add a solid black generator under each image and it works great.

The problem is that I have 60+ images and I want to avoid to cut the video or add the generator manually for every image. Is there a way to paste a generator below every image? As you can see in the image, the duration of each image changes, so the brown boxes (solid black background) should match the duration of each connected image on top. Is there a way to automate this?

[image]

Comment: Simply having a black background for the whole duration of the project isn't an option? Usually you would just have a black background that is visible whenever there is footage that isn't matching the aspect ratio of the project/taking up the whole screen.

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I'm switching back and forth between the slides and the video, so I only need a black background when there's a slide showing

Comment: Ah I see the video makes it more clear, I thought you had cuts, in that case you need a bit more manual work of course.

Comment: How can I explain it better?

Comment: I've edited your question a bit in a way that makes the issue a bit more clear. Does that still reflect the issue properly in your opinion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the answer from someone at [fcp.co](http://fcp.co). He made a video: [vimeo.com/93836074](http://vimeo.com/93836074)

Basically:

- add the generator to the timeline (don't worry about setting the duration since you're going to delete it)
- turn it into a compound clip, delete it from the timeline (since it gets added to the event manager)
- copy the image frames and paste them with the playhead at the first image
- create a compound clip with all images (the ones in the bottom, so there's an actual image on top)
- right click to `open it in timeline`
- select the black compound clip in the event viewer and press `x` then `d` (black gets added)
- press `down arrow` and repeat `x` then `d`

Pretty slick

Comment: If that solved your issue you can accept your own answer as the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this by altering the order of your layers. If you put the black on the bottom and razor away the main clip video when you want to go to slides it will work off a single generator. You just need to seperate the video and audio tracks.